# How to chain three catkin workspaces?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, setup.bash, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you chain three catkin workspaces so that their setup.bash files don't conflict?

I tried following the instructions [in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying), but they're a bit confusing and don't seem to be correct.

My workspaces are:

1. the base Kinetic workspace installed into the standard `/opt/ros/kinetic` location
2. a workspace containing third-party packages not available in kinetic (such as robot_upstart), at `/usr/local/mybot/overlay`
3. a workspace containing my custom application and packages at `/usr/local/mybot/ros`

Each workspace builds fine when I run catkin_make inside them. However, I can't source their setup.bash scripts to expose all their packages to ROS.

I'm using:

1. `rospack list|grep -i actionlib` to determine if the base Kinetic workspace is accessible, called check A.
2. `rospack list|grep -i upstart` to determine if the second workspace is accessible, called check B.
3. `rospack list|grep -i mybot` to determine if the third workspace is accessible, called check C.

If I run `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, then A passes, B fails, and C fails, as expected.

If I then run `source /usr/local/mybot/overlay/devel/setup.bash`, then A passes, B passes, and C fails, as expected.

If I then run `source /usr/local/mybot/ros/devel/setup.bash`, then A passes, B fails unexpectedly, but C passes.

So it seems that my third workspace is overwriting the environment set by the second workspace. How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238679/how-to-chain-three-catkin-workspaces?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible to source multiple workspaces and use the combined environment of them. You can source a setup file and pass `--extend` which will extend the current environment (set by another workspace before) instead of "resetting" the environment.

Please see http://answers.ros.org/question/64702/overlaying-multiple-catkin-devel-spaces-at-the-same-time/ for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Workspaces don't extend the environment; they set it.

The first time you build a workspace, it captures the existing ROS environment and creates a setup file that overlays the new workspace on the existing environment variables. When you source the setup file from this workspace, it **sets** the environment variables to overlay this workspace on your previous environment.

This means that you only need to source one setup.bash for the workspace at the top of your set of overlays, and that it will always produce the same environment.

To build your overlay, you should:

1. remove the build and devel directories from your workspaces, to reset them to a clean state
2. source `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and build workspace B
3. source workspace B and build workspace C

To use your overlay, you just need to source the setup file in workspace C

If you need to make minor changes in workspace B, you can rebuild it with any environment, but if you need to to a complete rebuild of workspace B, you should source `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before you do, so that you don't overlay it on your other workspaces.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-04**:
It is possible to extend the environment rather then (re)setting it. Please see other answer.